# Display Different Header Text In Each Wordpress Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a custom wordpress theme, and I want to have title/description in the middle of the header section.
title/description will not be static for all pages; I want to set them from the wp dashboard for each page.

Is there a way to do this? (without using if/else statement).

Comment: your question is not completely described. please provide some sample codes. and let us know where do you want exactly set that parameters. 
anyway Ill post an example for you asap

Answer (score 1):

you can set the parameters as **custom fields** [read here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/)

by using the `get_post_meta('key')` you can return that on your code.